# How to get from Detroit Airport to Greyhound Station?

Tags: airport-transfer, greyhound, michigan, detroit, dtw

How do I get from Detroit Metro Airport to the Greyhound Station on Howard street? My flight lands at 8:00am and the bus leaves at 12:10 from the Greyhound Station. How can I get to the station on time without getting a taxi?

Apparently, according to the online schedule, Smartbus 125 is not going all the way to the station from 8:45 to 2:45, but rather stops at Jefferson and Coolidge, so if I am reading the schedule correctly, that is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

[Google's public transportation map option](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Detroit+Metropolitan+Wayne+County+Airport+%28DTW%29,+Detroit+Metropolitan+Wayne+County+Airport,+Detroit+Metro+Airport,+Detroit,+MI&daddr=Greyhound+Package+Express,+1001+Howard+Street,+Detroit,+MI+48226&hl=en&sll=42.327363,-83.05457&sspn=0.005949,0.008562&geocode=FVcMhAIdCRII-yH7mL8lz8BBIykFs_DaXU87iDH7mL8lz8BBIw%3BFRnghQIdq6AM-ykdtdNtRy07iDHu6EhvsrU7MA&oq=detro&t=h&dirflg=r&ttype=dep&date=12%2F05%2F13&time=8:00am&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ls&z=11&start=0) would give you other alternatives.  You will still need to change the bus or 2 but it should get you there on time.

As far as [Route 125](http://www.smartbus.org/schedules/overview/Pages/default.aspx) is concerned it has 2 routes: Long and Short and unfortunately your arrival time doesn't allow you to take advantage of the Long route (which will take you to the bus terminal) as the last one for the morning run will leave airport at 7:30 am.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if public transport isn't available [skoot](https://www.rideskoot.com/) shared shuttle will take you downtown cheaper than a cab.